# How to call a protocol function from a non-conforming class?

Tags: swift, casting, protocols

I'm working with protocol and my app crashes when I try to call it from a class which doesn't conform to the protocol.

Playground code of the issue:

```
import Cocoa

var str = "Hello, playground"

public protocol example {
    func artihmetic(x: Int, y: Int) -> Int
}

class A : example {
    func artihmetic(x: Int, y: Int) -> Int { return x + y }
}

class B : example {
    func artihmetic(x: Int, y: Int) -> Int { return x * y }
}

class C {

    public init() {}

    func callArithmetic() {
        let x = 2, y = 2
        let z = (self as! example).artihmetic(x: x, y: y)
        print(z)
    }
}

let instC = C()
instC.callArithmetic()
```

This code crashes and I get this error:

```
Could not cast value of type '__lldb_expr_1.C' (0x112cd91c0) to '__lldb_expr_1.example' (0x7fff993f57e8)
```

I want to know if there is any alternate way or if it is possible to call a protocol function from a non-conforming class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self as! example
```

when you do that, the compiler will be like, "umm ok let me try that. Let's see the the type of `self`...ok. `self` is of type `C`. Is `C` a subclass of another type that conforms to `example`? No. Ok let me trying something else. Does the `C` class itself ever adopt the `example` protocol? No.! That's bad. I can't succeed. Oh shoot, they're using `!` with `as`...I have to crash"

`C` needs to adopt the `example` protocol. Are you doing that? No!

Another more clear example is:

```
protocol Feeder {
    func nurse()
}

class Human {
    func eat() {
        print("eat")
    }
}

class Man: Human{

}

class Woman: Human, Feeder {
    func nurse() {
        print("nurse baby")
    }
}

let human1: Human = Man()
let human2: Human = Woman()

func isFeeder(human: Human) {
    if let feeder = human as? Feeder { // very similar to: `self as! example`
        print("human is feeder!")
    } else {
        print("human is not feeder!")
    }
}

isFeeder(human: human1) // human is not feeder!
isFeeder(human: human2) // human is feeder!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is thinking that Swift has some sort of structural typing, that says

> Hey, these types are similar enough in their structure (the methods, properties, etc. that they have), I should be able to freely cast between them.

That's not at all the case. Swift has a "nominal type system" for everything but tuple and function types. Two structs could have the exact same implementation, but different names, and they would still be distinct, incompatible types.

Comment: But `C` is  not similar at all to `A`, `B`, or the requirements from `protocol example`. Why should one think that `self as! example` does *not* crash?

Comment: @MartinR A knowledgeable Swift developer obviously would. But OP clearly seems to think that `callArithmetic()`, with its `let x = 2, y = 2` local variables would be close enough to `func artihmetic(x: Int, y: Int) -> Int` that they built an expectation for this to work.

Comment: @MartinR look at OP's update on the original post. My hypothesis was correct